# No Activity found to handle Intent{ act=android.intent.action.CALL dat=Phone number:1 }?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

My program compiles, and works on everything it proposes, except when I try to use the phone call feature, it breaks. I've already changed the `manifest`, the `Activity`, and the main class, entered the necessary permissions, but it does not work. The error occurs at line 50 of this code: https://ideone.com/JrdBrp . The class is called `StudentCall`.

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        startActivity(it);//line 50
    }
}
```

The error message is:
`"android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent {act = android.intent.action.CALL dat = Phone number: 1}"`.
And that class is called by the MainStudent class, inserted in this code: https://ideone.com/b4jyU6,

```
public void call(View view){
    Intent it = new Intent(this, StudentCall.class);
    it.putExtra("students", students);
    startActivity(it);
}
```

the function that calls the previous class, is called "call", at line 31. Could you please helpe me?

Comment: please add code your manifest file

Comment: Hello, this is my manifest file: [link] https://ideone.com/htUmGS

Comment: try this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41988171/android-content-activitynotfoundexception-no-activity-found-to-handle-intent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("Phone number:" + student.phone_number);
```

This is not a valid `Uri`. `Phone number:` is not a valid scheme, and `1` is unlikely to be a valid phone number.

Use the `tel:` scheme and an actual phone number.